# flask migration does nothing

Tags: postgresql, flask, flask-migrate

I have a project I've been working on. Recently swapped out my os drive and did a fresh install of windows. Obviously rebuilding my workflow and I encountered an error.

I try to use db migrate in the context of upgrading my new empty database with the migrations already existing from the my current project. When I try to db upgrade from my venv, nothing happens. Not an error, a message or anything. I check the db and nothing is done. Any ideas what could be causing this? I updated my keys and db logins/uri to reflect the new database still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted my venv, rebuilt it and reinstalled requirements and everything worked. Hope this helps someone out there.